# position a web page in the center for all screen size

Tags: html, css, size, screen

I am using HTML and CSS.
I can't display all of my content in the middle of the screen for varying display sizes.
I have attempted to use % in place of PX but it's unsuitable for small screen size such as 800*600 pixels.
Also I have performed web searches but my lack of in-depth knowledge of HTML is hindering my progress.
my code is this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#Line5
{
   color: #7B7BC0;
   background-color: #7B7BC0;
   border-width: 0px;
}
#wb_Text1 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0px #8B8B00 solid;
   padding: 0;
}
<body>
<hr id="Line5" align="center" style="position:relative;top:28px;width:803px;height:93px ;z-index:0;">
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:406px;top:58px;width:308px;height:36px;text-align:center;z-index:1;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:32px;"><strong><em>SAMPLE TEXT</em></strong></span></div>
```

can someone correct this piece of code for me?

Comment: Is this the full file contents?

Comment: no its not full code,the abve piece of code is not writed by me and automatically created by WYSIWYG web builder program.

Comment: In that case I would dump that WYSIWYG your using and start fresh from the jsFiddle @Anup included in his answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what your desired output is like. But check this out.

[Click Here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vdFgG/)

```
<div id="wb_Text1">
<span class="head"><strong><em>SAMPLE TEXT</em></strong></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here updated code and its working fine.

```
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:relative;display:table;margin-left:auto;width:100%;height:36px;text-align:center;margin-right:auto;z-index:1;background-color: #7B7BC0;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:32px;"><strong><em>SAMPLE TEXT</em></strong></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about your question but I think Either of the examples below could work for you ;
if you want it to be standards compliant, use this in your stylesheet:

```
body { 
text-align:center; 
} 
#mainContainer { 
margin:0 auto; 
}
```

the body thing makes it work in IE, the `margin:0 auto;` makes it center in most other browsers.

you might have to go in and reset some of your main containers to `text-align:left;` because the body `text-align:center` sometimes cascades down into the site content, but you can counteract that by adding

```
text-align:left; 
to #mainContainer
```

Or,
There may be better methods, but this works in all browsers so far :

```
body {width: /*fixed width or percentage here*/; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background: #; color: #; font: ; text-align: center;}
```

or set body width to 100% and then just make a container div for your page

```
#container {width: /*fixed width or percentage here*/; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background: #; color: #; font: ; text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also not quite sure what you're asking for. I'm interpreting it as you wanting the div to be centered vertically and horizontally, so that's what I'm going for.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wb_Text1">
    <b>SAMPLE TEXT</b>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; //these two are so that the automatic margins work for the div.
}
#wb_Text1 {
    height: 93px; //or whatever height you want
    width: 300px; //or whatever width you want (can be in %)
    background-color: #7B7BC0;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: 32px Arial;
    line-height: 93px; //should be same as the height if you've only got one line of text and you want it vertically centered in the div
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin: calc(0.5 * (50% - 46.5px)) auto; //first value makes it vertically centered, the second makes it horizontally centered.
    margin: -webkit-calc(0.5 * (50% - 46.5px)) auto; //for Safari
}
```

Here's what's happening inside the `calc()`:

`50%` gives you half the total height of the page,

`46.5px` is half of the `div`'s height, which in this case is 93,

`50% - 46.5px` gives you the amount of space needed to center the div vertically

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shiazure/hA9KB/

Comment: thank you dear friend,i attached my full code in previous post. can you tell me what changes must be taken for above code and where i must put your modified code. thank you again for your help

Comment: The WYSIWYG code is at best convoluted. I'm assuming you just want text with a solid background that's some fixed width and height, so the HTML & CSS I gave you is all you need to put. Delete whatever the editor gave you, and you should be good. I've parsed my code so you can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

i thank all those who helped me. Problem was solved by adding the following code.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    div#container
    {
       width: 990px;
       position: relative;
       margin-top: 0px;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       text-align: left;
    }
    ....
    .....
    ........
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    ...
    ....
```

Thank you so much that help a rookie !